# Prove that composing two distribution functions results in another distribution function

Tags: probability

If $F$ is a distribution function and $T: \Re \rightarrow \Re$ surjective and not decreasing, prove that $F \circ T$ is distribution function.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to prove this property of distribution functions?

I know which are the properties of function to be a distribution function, but I don't know how to apply those in the composition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketches (justifications will involve the given assumptions on $T$ and the fact that $F$ is a distribution function):

- If $x \le y$ then $T(x) \le T(y)$ and thus $F(T(x)) \le F(T(y))$.
- If $x \to \infty$, then $T(x) \to \infty$, so $F(T(x)) \to 1$.
- If $x \to -\infty$, then $T(x) \to -\infty$, so $F(T(x)) \to 0$.
- If $x \searrow x_0$, then $T(x) \searrow T(x_0)$ so $F(T(x)) \downarrow F(T(x_0))$.